# Pandas multiple row and column selection by logical

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

So I have a DataFrame called trials, and a series of logical values called random.  random is a logical series the same length as the number of rows in each columns in trials.

```
 trials.shape
Out[72]: (199, 4)

random.value_counts()
Out[74]: 
False    192
True       7
dtype: int64
```

I used the following solution to get the rows of all the columns in trials but it is not scalable, what if I have more columns than this is feasible for or if I want to simultaneously filter for columns and rows?

```
trials[['Choice','LeftContrast','RightContrast','feedback']][random]
Out[67]: 
    Choice LeftContrast RightContrast feedback
16   [1.0]       [0.25]        [0.25]    [1.0]
25   [1.0]        [1.0]         [1.0]    [1.0]
79   [1.0]        [1.0]         [1.0]   [-1.0]
80   [1.0]        [1.0]         [1.0]   [-1.0]
93   [1.0]        [1.0]         [1.0]    [1.0]
122  [1.0]        [0.5]         [0.5]   [-1.0]
166  [0.0]       [0.25]        [0.25]   [-1.0]
```

How could I write this so that I don't have to specify all the columns I want compared?  Calling ":" creates an error:

```
trials[[:]][random]
  File "<ipython-input-68-a82ea1b0ab14>", line 1
    trials[[:]][random]
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Using `.iloc` also produces an error.

```
trials.iloc[random,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

What if I wanted to use logicals to assess both rows and columns?

Comment: Try `trials.loc[random, :]`

Comment: Have you tried ```trials[trials.columns][random]```?

Comment: Hi I voted to close my own question because I think it is a duplicate of others.  Psidom's solution worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a dataframe by multiple column(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: Yes it does.  When I posted I just couldn't find good answers but now I've found many.